# How to get locale in Spring WebFlux?

Tags: java, spring-boot, locale, spring-webflux

I want to get current locale but the context always return default locale. It works with MVC but not with WebFlux.

Thank for your help!

```
package co.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.Locale;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {
    private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public HelloController(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        return messageSource.getMessage("hello", null, locale);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the locale you are expecting and what it is returning?

Comment: @DhawalKapil I have `message.properties` and `messages_fr.properties` but webflux always return default locale `en` not `fr`. It's okay with mvc.

Comment: I think it depends on the current JVM locale. I am not sure if there is anything Webflux/Web related to it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do not use `LocaleContextHolder` in WebFlux environment but add `Locale` as a method parameter instead:

```java
@RestController
public class LocaleController {
    @GetMapping("/locale")
    String getLocale(Locale locale) {
        return locale.toLanguageTag();
    }
}
```

Test:

```sh
$ curl localhost:8080/locale -H 'Accept-Language: en-US'
en-US
$ curl localhost:8080/locale -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB'
en-GB
```

For more info see:

- [Spring WebFlux. Annotated Controllers. Method Arguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-ann-arguments)

Comment: Can you tell me the reason why `LocaleContextHolder` does not work with WebFlux?

Comment: Internally it relies on `ThreadLocal` which not supposed to be used in WebFlux because of its event driven nature

Answer (score 1):

Earlier I was using spring-web dependency in my project and was able to get locale from WebRequest.

But when we have migrated project from spring-web to spring-web-flux then we can get locale using LocaleContextHolder as below:

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```